# change hostname in python

Tags: python, wmi, windows-11

I was referring to an older stack overflow post:[How do I change a computer's name with the WMI module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010449/how-do-i-change-a-computers-name-with-the-wmi-module-in-python).
I tried to do the same thing, but upon doing so, I got a return of (5,). This is a tuple, but I was hoping I could find it in the WMI docs by ignoring the tuple and using the actual integer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants in this section, but could not.

```
        context = wmi.WMI()

        for system in context.Win32_ComputerSystem():
            print(system)
            q = system.Rename('ballcccc', None, None)
            print(q)
```

I tried this, [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/rename-method-in-class-win32-computersystem) state that you can use a NULL parameter for the USER & PASS arguments.
My question is: How can I properly change the hostname of my windows 11 computer in Python?
Using the answer given, I now get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ballc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1340, in connect
    obj = GetObject(moniker)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ballc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 86, in GetObject
    return Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ballc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 103, in Moniker
    moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147217394, 'OLE error 0x8004100e', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\work\auto.py", line 49, in <module>
    o.changeName()
  File "D:\work\auto.py", line 41, in changeName
    context = wmi.WMI(namespace="Root\CIMV2")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ballc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1354, in connect
    handle_com_error()
  File "C:\Users\ballc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 258, in handle_com_error
    raise klass(com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217394, 'OLE error 0x8004100e', None, None)>
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: the version is 3.11

Comment: A return value of `(5,)` means [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). So the call does accept `None` (or NULL) for these parameters, however, the user in the context of the call is not authorized to perform this action. Per the [**Remarks** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/rename-method-in-class-win32-computersystem#remarks), you can only do this if you're targeting the local computer and a local admin of the local computer. If you're targeting a remote system, you must authenticate.

Comment: I am using my own computer and I am an admin of my computer.

Comment: @Noah are you running the script as an administrator?

Comment: no, removing the namespace kwarg then running as admin gave me a 0 which indicated success, but my hostname was not changed.

Comment: update: I got it, must have been an invalid hostname i was trying to change it to